# Discrete version of Dudley's inequalilty: Assuming set is finite wlog?

Tags: probability-theory, empirical-processes

I'm self-studying Vershynin's High-dimensional probability book. I have a question about the proof of Theorem 8.1.4:

> Let $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ be a mean-zero random process on a metric space $(T,d)$, with sub-gaussian increments. Then:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\sup_{t\in T}X_t\leq  C K \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}2^{-k}\sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,2^{-k})}
> $$
> Here, $C$ is a constant and $\mathcal{N}(T,d,2^{-k})$ the covering number of the set $T$ with balls of radius $2^{-k}$.

**Question:** In the proof, it is stated that without loss of generality, we may assume that $T$ is finite. Why can we do that?

---

By sub-gaussian increments, the following is meant:

> Consider a random process $(x_t)_{t\in T}$ on a metric space $(T,d)$. We say that the process has sub-gaussian increments, if there exists a constant $K>0$, such that for all $t,x\in T$,
> $$
> ||X_t-X_s||_{\psi_2}\leq Kd(t,s)
> $$
> Here, $||\cdot||_{\psi_2}$ is the sub-gaussian norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an explanation:
To avoid issues with measurability, Vershynin defines:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in T}X_t]:=\sup_{T'\in \mathcal{T}}\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in T'}X_t]
$$
Where $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of finite subsets of $T$ (see footnote 3 on p.151).
So, the supremum is only taken over finite sets $T'$.
The proof in Theorem 8.1.4 for finite sets gives us:
$$
\sup_{T'\in \mathcal{T}}\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in T'}X_t]
\leq 
\sup_{T'\in \mathcal{T}}CK\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}2^{-k}\sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T',d,2^{-k})}
$$
And since $T'\subset T$, we have $\mathcal{N}(T',d,2^{-k})\leq \mathcal{N}(T,d,2^{-k})$, and so:
$$
\leq CK\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}2^{-k}\sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,2^{-k})}
$$

---

I am still curious whether this result holds more generally, i.e. without defining $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in T}X_t]$ as Vershynin does.
On the other hand, $\sup_{t\in T}X_t$ may be non-measurable, which would mean that the inequality does not make sense in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the exact answer to your question but I had same problem in Generic chaining problem and here is my solution to that problem

<(Generic chaining bound)
Let $(X_t)_{t \in T}$ be a mean-zero random process on a infinite ($T$ is infinite set) metric space $(T, d)$ with sub-gaussian increments i.e. it's satisfy
\begin{equation}\label{eq-sub-gaussian-incriment-metric}
 \lVert X_t - X_s \rVert_{\psi_2} \leq K d(t,s) \text{ for all } t,s \in T.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation} \label{eq-generic-chaining-bound}
 \sup_{T_0 \subset T, |T_0|<|N|} E \max_{t \in T_0} X_t \leq CK \gamma_2(T,d)
\end{equation}

Which means that we want to prove
$$
 E \max_{t \in W} X_t \leq CK \gamma_2(T,d)
$$
for every  finite $W \subset T$.

remark

Let's consider some examples of spaces and their $\gamma_2$ functions. We only focus on standard euclidean norm, so in this remark we don't write, which norm we use.

$A = \{-1 , 0, 1\}, B = \{-1 ,  1\} \subset R$
$$
 \gamma_2(A) = 1 \leq 2 = \gamma_2(B)
$$

$A = [-1;1], B = \{-1 ,  1\} \subset R$
$$
 1 \leq  \gamma_2(A)  \leq 2 = \gamma_2(B)
$$

$A = [-1;1], B = [-1;-0,5] \cup [0,5;1] \subset R$
$$
 \gamma_2(A)  \leq \gamma_2(B)
$$

$A = [-1;1], B = [-2;2] \subset R$
$$
 \gamma_2(A)  \leq \gamma_2(B)
$$

Remark show us that in theorem we can't simply say
$$
 E \max_{t \in W} X_t \leq CK \gamma_2(W,d) \leq CK \gamma_2(T,d)
$$
so we need another tool.\

(Generic chaining bound)\
If $K=0$ then left hand equal to $0$ so inequality is trivial. If $K \neq 0$ and $\gamma_2(T,d) = +\infty$ then inequality is trivial in this case too. So we can assume by linearity of norms and expectation that $K=1$ and $\gamma_2(T,d) < +\infty$.
Let's fix some finite $W \subset T$, there is $n \in N$ such that $|W| < 2^{2^n}$. Let's fix some $e >0$ too, there is $(V_n)_{n \in N}$ admissible sequences such that $|V_k| = 2^{2^k}$ $k = 1,2,...$ and
$$
 \gamma_2(T,d) + e = \inf_{(T_k)} \sup_{t \in T} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{k/2}d(t,T_k) +e > \sup_{t \in T} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{k/2}d(t,V_k) .
$$
Denote by $W_k = V_k$ $k = 0,1,...,n$ and $W_{n+i} = W_n \cup W$ $i=1,2,...$ and use same theorem for $W_{n+1}$ (we can do it because $W_{n+1}$ is finite)
\begin{multline*}
 E \max_{t \in W} \leq E \max_{t \in W_{n+1}} X_t \leq \\
 C\gamma_2(W_{n+1},d) = C\inf_{(T_k)} \sup_{t \in W_{n+1}} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{k/2}d(t,T_k) \leq\\
 C\sup_{t \in W_{n+1}} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{k/2}d(t,W_k) = C\sup_{t \in W_{n+1}} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k/2}d(t,W_k) \leq \\
 C\sup_{t \in T} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k/2}d(t,W_k) = C\sup_{t \in T} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k/2}d(t,V_k) \leq \\ C\sup_{t \in T} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{k/2}d(t,V_k)<  C (\gamma_2(T,d) + e) 
$$
\end{multline*}
Finally note that $\epsilon$ can be arbitrary small, which is complete the proof.